# How to create custom higher order function like .maps() or .filter() works in Swift

Tags: swift, dictionary, higher-order-functions

I am just looking for the internal implementation of higher order function in swift like map, filter, reduce.

According to apple documentation.

> @inlinable public func map(_ transform: (Element) throws -> T) rethrows -> [T]
>
> Returns an array containing the results of mapping the given closure  over the sequence's elements.

For e.g;

```
var arr = [1,2,3,4,5]

print(arr.map({$0*5}))
```

Output will be

> [5,10,15,20,25];

or

```
print(arr.map({String($0)}))
```

I just eager to know how the computation basically works here or higher order internally works. Could you please help me here, how map works here like what to do with the values (multiply or converting into string).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can create custom map like this. Under the sequence, you create your own higher order function.

```
extension Sequence {

public func customMap2<T>(_ transform: (Element) -> T) -> [T] {

    var result = [T]()

    for item in self {
        result.append(transform(item))
    }

    return result
   }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

`map` takes a closure as its only input argument, which transforms a single element of the sequence to another type. `map` iterates through all elements of the sequence it is called on and executes the closure on them and hence returns the transformed value for each original element.

For your concrete examples, the first one simply multiplies each element of `arr` by 5, so each element of the resulting array will contain the original element at the given index multiplied by 5.

The second example simply converts each `Int` to a `String`.

You can have a look at the [current implementation of Sequence.map](https://github.com/apple/swift/blob/51bbaebd0895c25ad23c2c51eedb0b2ee0ca0206/stdlib/public/core/Sequence.swift#L601) on GitHub, since Swift is an open-source language:

```
@inlinable
  public func map<T>(
    _ transform: (Element) throws -> T
  ) rethrows -> [T] {
    let initialCapacity = underestimatedCount
    var result = ContiguousArray<T>()
    result.reserveCapacity(initialCapacity)

    var iterator = self.makeIterator()

    // Add elements up to the initial capacity without checking for regrowth.
    for _ in 0..<initialCapacity {
      result.append(try transform(iterator.next()!))
    }
    // Add remaining elements, if any.
    while let element = iterator.next() {
      result.append(try transform(element))
    }
    return Array(result)
  }
```

Comment: Thanks David for the explanation. Could you please also let me know that here transform converts my element into String or multiply by 5. Right?

Comment: @VikashSinha have a look this its well explained https://www.hackingwithswift.com/articles/173/inside-the-standard-library-sequence-map